# Vertical align list-group bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How I can align bootstrap group center?

I have code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              Your dialogs
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="avatar">
                  <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="user-name">Dima</div>
                <div class="message float-left">Hello?</div>
                <span class="date text-mutted float-right">19:07</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-name">Jack</div>
                  <div class="message float-left">Nope</div>
                  <span class="date text-mutted float-right">20:07</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-name">Madonna</div>
                  <div class="message float-left">Lol?</div>
                  <span class="date text-mutted float-right">22:04</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Avatar and time elements I get not on center.
I tryied do align-items-center, but I get all items on center horizontally...
How I can fix this?

Example:

http://jsbin.com/raqatuyeho/1/edit

Comment: You want the time centered to the right of the avatar? Where did you attempt to use `align-items-center`?

Comment: Not working: `align-items-center`: http://jsbin.com/limibayoru/1/edit?html,output

Comment: It's `align-items-center`, not `align-item-center` http://jsbin.com/qibivaxape/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use bootstrap utility class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              Your dialogs
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center">
     
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-100">
                  <div class="user-name">Jack</div>
                  <div class="message bg-light">Nope</div>
                  </div>
                  <span class="date text-mutted ml-auto">20:07</span>
    
                  
              </li>              
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center">
     
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-100">
                  <div class="user-name">Jack</div>
                  <div class="message bg-light">Nope</div>
                  </div>
                  <span class="date text-mutted ml-auto">20:07</span>
    
                  
              </li>  
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center">
     
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="w-100">
                  <div class="user-name">Jack</div>
                  <div class="message bg-light">Nope</div>
                  </div>
                  <span class="date text-mutted ml-auto">20:07</span>
    
                  
              </li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. See please what I get: http://jsbin.com/limibayoru/1/edit?html,output

Comment: But message How I can pass to bottom?

Comment: please checkout

Comment: so where you want your message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169854/discussion-between-patelarpan-and-jadasdas).

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML like this

```
<li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="avatar">
                  <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="user-name">Dima</div>
                  <div class="message float-left">Hello?</div>
                </div>
                <span class="date text-mutted float-right">19:07</span>
              </li>
```

Also add css

```
.list-group-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.date.text-mutted {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please check my HTML code again. Wrap your user-name and message divs in another div. I have done that above. I cant see it in your fiddle. Check http://jsbin.com/johevowusa/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: See please: http://jsbin.com/bataxunofu/1/edit?html,output I need avatar do verticle align middle

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              Your dialogs
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="avatar">
                  <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="user-name">Dima</div>
                <div class="message ">Hello?</div>
                <span class="date text-mutted">19:07</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-name">Jack</div>
                  <div class="message">Nope</div>
                  <span class="date text-mutted">20:07</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-name">Madonna</div>
                  <div class="message">Lol?</div>
                  <span class="date text-mutted">22:04</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```